# VBA Excel button inactive after one-click Option button (ActiveX controls)

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 Option buttons.
The problem is, that when I click on one of them I can't execute of the process when clicking on the same option button again.
Could anyone tell me how to do it?

[image]

I found some threads here, but without solution:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f942f0e2-3daf-4a06-a7c9-3904a88e49bc/macro-called-twice-on-single-button-click

I can also do the DoubleClick

```
 Private Sub SchematicImage2_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
```

But it doesn't solve my problem, because I want to have the result after one click and be able to click on the same button with code execution again. The button seems to be no longer active after one click. I don't want that.

How can I do this?

Comment: Where do you have those Option buttons? On a form, or on a sheet?

Comment: I have them on a sheet

Comment: Have a separate go button which runs the macro and looks to see which button is active, rather than using the radio buttons to launch the macro

Comment: Using the double click event will work. The Option Button value will be, anyhow, all the time 'True`... Try, please: `Private Sub OptionButton1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    MsgBox IIf(Me.OptionButton1.value = True, "True", "False")
End Sub`. You cannot understand anything here. I will post an answer and delete it if it doesn't work as you need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `DblClick` event, please:

```
Private Sub SchematicImage2_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    MsgBox IIf(Me.SchematicImage2.value = True, "True", "False")
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not working, because now I have no access to the 2nd button. When I click it it doesn't react.

Comment: What do you mean by "have no access"? Cannot execute double click on the Option button "SchematicImage2"? Isn't this an option button?

Comment: Yes indeed. I click it and nothing is being executed.

Comment: No 'click' it... Double click it!

Comment: @Mariusz Krukar: Did you double click it? If yes, what happened?